# package ‘olapR’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)

Tags: r

Good evening,

I need to link my RStudio with the OLAP system, but R return me this message:

**package ‘olapR’ is not available (for R version 3.5.1)**

Somebody know how I can around the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Francesco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Microsoft `olapR` is only available if you use the Microsoft R client:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/471e1d45-ac2f-49be-a3c3-2f6bb7d09b96/want-to-start-testing-olapr-package

> olapR package is only shipped with RClient.
>   You might want to install that from
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-r/r-client-get-started
>   and then get started.